# Блок «Поделиться» от Яндекса, не работает Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, share, ya-share2, opengraph

Страница http://malina.com.ru/item/underwear_kit/red/

Краулер Фейсбука не берет `og:title`, `og:description` и `og:image`.

Answer (score 2):

Фейсбук не видит `opengraph`-разметку на вашем сайте.

В это можно убедиться, запустив [Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmalina.com.ru%2Fitem%2Funderwear_kit%2Fred%2F).

Возможно, проблема в кодировке, такую ошибку показывает [Open Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/).